# background images, among other things wont show online but work locally

Tags: html, css, image

I realize this has been asked a trillion times, but I can't seem to get my background image to show up online. it was working fine locally.

I used a relative path name to Banner_hd.jpg in my img folder, while my css was in my css folder.

background-image: url(../img/Banner_hd.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;

I tried with and without quotes, i tried image-url instead of just url, background instead of background-image, I tried converting to png, and renaming to banner.jpg. I also tried a url to the web address like url(http://myweb.com/img/Banner_hd.jpg) and still no luck.

what else can I try? when I used page inspector I found the image had a 404 not found error and was listed as html/text, while only one image seemed to come up properly, though not sure why.

Please let me know if I can provide more relevant info, thanks!

heres the relevant code:

```
   html:

<div class="cover">

        <div class="cover-text">            
            <img src="img/sm.jpg" class="img-circle">          
            <img src=" img/Logo-new.png " class="logo">        
      </div>
    </div>

css:

.cover {
    background-image: url('../img/Banner_hd.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: feel free to show us your code.

Comment: html:

<div class="cover">

        <div class="cover-text">            
            <img src="img/sm.jpg" class="img-circle">          
            <img src=" img/Logo-new.png " class="logo">        
      </div>
    </div>

css:

.cover {
    background-image: url('../img/Banner_hd.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

Comment: You can Edit your question and put the entire code there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to put the whole path to your banner like this:
url(http://somewebsite.com/css/img/Banner_hd.jpg)

Also you mentioned that right path to you image is url(/css/img/Banner_hd.jpg), try to you it.

Comment: sorry let me clarify the folder structure: 
<code>project
   - img
     -Banner_hd.jpg
   - css
     -Hstyles.css</code>

Answer (score 0):

if your images are local, and your code is online, your problem will lie there. Its HARD to guestimate at where your problem lay with NO CODE to test. Otherwise, Try a direct URL such as `http://yoursite.com/img/dawn-sm.jpg`

Comment: okay I tried this

background-image: url(http://myweb.com/img/Banner_hd.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
still nothing... would I need to reference the image in the html as well as the css?

note: thats obviously not the actual name of the website, you understand of course I'm not confident enough to share the actual name/web address.

Comment: must add `http://` in front to direct it correctly to the website. And... confidence is built on trial and error. you will fail alot... but eventually you will get it. :)

Comment: oh I did in the css, forgot here when I retyped it. Its my first site, but I still know that much haha

Answer (score 0):

I want to say I solved it, but I don't think I had anything to do with it. gave up last night, went to bed, woke up and the background image was suddenly working fine. I guess it was on the server's end. Thanks for all your help guys! :)